# How to replace login user for phpmyadmin on remote ubuntu 20?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to replace login user for phpMyAdmin on remote Ubuntu 20.

I opened file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and modified `$dbuser` parameter:

```
# $dbuser='phpmyadmin';

$dbuser='NewUser';

$dbpass='Newpassword';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='localhost';
$dbport='3306';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

I am able to login with `NewUser` and `Newpassword`, but I also can entered into the system with `root` and `Newpassword`. My prior login  `phpmyadmin` - does not work(I commented it above).

I restarted Apache with command :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

How to disable `root` user for phpMyAdmin?

Actually my dev site was hacked and I lost all my data on MySQL.
Not big deal as it was dev site only, but how to make my site  safer ? I think changing login to phpMyAdmin is one step... Any other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. To disable `root` login access to phpMyAdmin, you have to set `AllowRoot` directive to `false` in your config.

Open `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`, search for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` and add `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;` below it. The code should look like this:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;
```